How does Gaza/Palestine have money?
What do they trade for to acquire goods? Why do these people have capacity of trade to acquire food and fuel and to what do they exchange that seeing how trade is among what is able to be produced, which is what in Gaza? What do they trade for their sustenance?

Right now, there is a humanitarian crisis in Gaza, including a risk of starvation. That they actually have money in any appreciable quantity is an assumption that may not be correct. That there are currently sources of food besides humanitarian aid, small-scale cultivation, and leftover storage also may not be correct.

so why dont you craft an answer instead of downvoting my queston huh

@max: As stated, the question could be rather complex, as I understand, as you are asking for Gaza and/or Palestine, where as I understand, the question may need more research to clarify if having Israeli currency satisfies this question, or if it is details on how they get said currency that would be elaborated on?

@max You shouldn't assume you know who has downvoted your posts.

They have currency to trade for goods so what do they trade? What do they produce or what service or labor do they provide? Or do they live off remittances? Or they live off American foreign aid?
